# How to extend a CSS/HTML content box to the bottom of browser/viewport window when other elements above it push it down?

Tags: html, css, height

like many others looking for CSS height solutions, I've had this issue on and off throughout the years. A simple jsfiddle is worth a thousand words:

http://jsfiddle.net/7dcjn/1/

I understand how to use height: 100% on the html and body to achieve partially what I would like to do.  I also just found out about the CSS3 box-sizing property, which again, fixes some of the issues.

However, I still have the issue where if you have a top header div1 that is 50px in height, then have a div2 below that with 100% height, the browser makes the div2 100% of the viewport height which then of course makes div2 run outside the body.  See the jsfiddle above or code below.

```
<div id="MainBody">
    <div id="TopHeader">My Top Header</div>
    <div id="ContentWrapper">
    How does one get this blue box to extend only to the bottom of the viewport/browser window?  In other words, the blue border needs to extend right up to the green box.
    </div>
</div>

html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 2px solid #00CC00;}
html, body, #MainBody, #ContentWrapper {height: 100%; min-height: 100%; box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
#MainBody {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 2px solid #CC0000;}
#TopHeader {height: 50px; background-color: #303030; padding: 10px; color: #FFFFFF;}
#ContentWrapper {margin: 0; padding: 20px 20px 0 20px; margin: 10px 10px 0 10px; border: 2px solid #0000CC;}
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at css `calc()`

Comment: I think this did the trick.  Setting ContentWrapper height: calc(100% - 80px); Seems to work in IE 10, Firefox 23, and Chrome 29.  Even works on my Galaxy S4 with Chrome.  See update here: http://jsfiddle.net/7dcjn/3/   Thanks!

Comment: A word of caution, I found out that the spaces before and after the minus sign in calc are very important, otherwise it doesn't work!

Comment: @qwarktastic calc does require that the header is of a fixed size, if that's not desired, check out my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the closest you'll get to actually fitting the box to the remaining space, that is to have the box fill the whole space and float the header over top of it so that the content gets pushed out of the way.

This is a better solution than `calc()` because the size of the header does not need to be set in order for this to work.

So you need to make a few modifications, `TopHeader` needs to be `float:left;width:100%;` and the margins on the `ContentWrapper` need to be changed so that it doesn't get pushed off of the bottom.

See my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dcjn/5/)

To adjust the spacing below the header for when the content starts you need to adjust hte bottom margin on `TopHeader`

Here's an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7dcjn/6/)

Comment: Thanks Don! Very nice solution. For my layout, the header was a fixed size so I wasn't too concerned.  However, I can see this as a more permanent solution in that it will require less fiddling when the header does change.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here's your solution bro:

The first styling of the css of the "contentWrapper" was false.

http://jsfiddle.net/xbV9A/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried a position:fixed on the ContentWrapper but that doesn't do quite what I need.  It will remove the scroll bars, but the blue box still extends beyond the body.  So if content goes into the blue box (like a map), it won't be sized correctly.

Comment: I've added a solution with "jsfiddle". check it out :]

Comment: Ah, so you changed the height of ContentWrapper from 100% to 75%?  Unfortunately this won't work either.  If you resize the viewport it won't stay extended to the bottom.  It will actually be much smaller than needed.